# Does anyone have any good examples of a .NET program that stays memory resident and runs an action on a timer?

Tags: c#, memory, taskbar

This program should not have a visible window, more like a daemon. (a taskbar program for instance) Any links or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to consider writing a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx).

If you just need to execute a specific action at certain times you could make use of the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler).

If you want an icon in the system tray you could write an ordinary Windows Forms application but have the main form hidden until the user requests it. This [article](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3336751/C-Tip-Placing-Your-C-Application-in-the-System-Tray.htm) explains how.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to run tasks on a timer, the Windows Task Scheduler's where it's at.

Answer (score 1):

When I've built applications that need this functionality before, I've **always used the Windows Task Scheduler** through a simple .NET library that I found.

**Please [see my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489999/how-can-i-schedule-tasks-in-a-winforms-app/2490142#2490142)** for some sample code and more explanation.